# React Basic Application works locally, but in Azure it does not load .CSS, .Ico, .JSON

Tags: css, reactjs, azure, react-router

I have a single web app which works locally and when deployed to Azure with a release pipeline all files seem to be deployed correctly
[image]

When I go to the website, to the .css url, the file is not loaded in the browser and its a 404.

[image]

The index.html is very simple:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en" dir="ltr"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon.png"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" async><link async rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ionicons.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-instantsearch-theme-algolia@4.0.0/style.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin="" async/><title>Isomorphic</title><link href="/static/css/main.48941814.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.b47e17ce.js"></script></body></html>
```

And as shown in the first screnshot, the file is there:

The only thing I can think of is that something is wrong with the web.config and it wont allow to serve .css or other types of files?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to your web app?

Comment: not really is Azure AD protected, so you will need my account and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the **StaticContent** rule, it seems to be rewriting all the requests to the **public** folder and from the console image you posted, it seems that your static content isn't located under **public**.

Hope it helps!